# Netlogo: choosing ranked n-of turtles to add to a certain value to a variable

Tags: social-networking, netlogo

I'm constructing a model to research opinion dynamics given certain network structures. In the model, there is a hypothetical 'dictator' who can hand out resources (or 'bribes') to certain nodes in the network. What I want is that the dictator can choose the top X% of nodes in the model who have the most positive opinions. (later I also want to the dictator to choose the nodes with the most network connections)

What's the best way to do this? I'm not sure how to use the n-of command for a 'ranked' n-of. Or is it better to use another term I'm not aware of?

```
ask n-of ??? turtles [set bribes (bribes + height-of-bribe)]
```

thanks!

edit:

currently, I have:

```
foreach sublist sort-on [(- total-motivation)] nodes 0 10 ask nodes [
set bribes (bribes + height-of-bribes)]
```

but I'm still getting errors. Any thoughts?

Edit 2:

Nevermind. It works. Thanks!

Comment: [`Sort-on`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dict/sort-on.html) combined with [`sublist`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dict/sort-on.html) might be what you need- rank your nodes based on your variable of choice and then take the top x number or percent.

Comment: Thanks! I've edited my question using your information because I still can't get it to work.

Comment: I used `turtles` in my answer. I can't figure out what nodes is, possibly a breed of turtles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you probably want the `max-n-of` primitive. There is no need to sort and take the first (or last) of the list. You probably want something like

```
ask max-n-of 10 turtles [total-motivation] [set bribes (bribes + height-of-bribes)]
```

When you later want the ones with the most links, just put [count my-links] instead of [total-motivation]

Comment: Great! Thanks! Still got a small problem though. Updated my original post.

Comment: Nevermind, found the solution. Thanks again for the help!